# Passing an array of 2 vectors as argument by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reference, arguments

I am trying to pass an array (size 2 for simplicity) of vectors as an argument to a method "writeToVector()".  This method will assign string values to the vector.

I've written a standalone test program (below) that works.  But it doesn't work when I integrate it into my real program.

Is there something wrong with my program below? Is it working only "by accident"?

I'm not sure if the signature of the "writeToVector()" method is correct.

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> ExtensionType;

void writeToVector(ExtensionType *extensions)
{
  extensions[0].push_back("A");
  extensions[1].push_back("B");
}

void main(void)
{
  ExtensionType extensions[2];
  getExtensions(extensions);
  for(// loop through array of vectors)
  {
    for(// loop through vector's elements)
    {
     // print vector contents
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does getExtensions(m_extensions); do? Does it modify the array? You'll have to show us the "real program".

Comment: That was a typo.  I've changed "m_extensions" to "extensions"

Comment: Still what does `getExtensions` do? As for the signature, you can always do `void writeToVector(ExtensionType[] extensions);` I guess, but I'm not sure it's strictly the same.

Comment: If we don't know what "it doesn't work" means, we can't answer. Does it crash? Does it not modify the vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is dangerous in that it *assumes* that a pointer passed to it points to the beginning of an array of size 2 or more. If this isn't the case, it will fall over in a heap. So better pass something that is guaranteed to have size 2, such as an `std::array<EtnensionType, 2>`.

```
void writeToVector(std::array<ExtensionType, 2>& extensions)
{
  extensions[0].push_back("A");
  extensions[1].push_back("B");
}
```

then

```
int main()
{
  std::array<ExtensionType, 2> extensions;
  getExtensions(extensions);
}
```

If you really are stuck with the array, then make sure it is size 2 only:

```
void writeToVector(ExtensionType (&extensions)[2])
{
  extensions[0].push_back("A");
  extensions[1].push_back("B");
}

int main()
{
  ExtensionType extensions[2];
  getExtensions(extensions);
}
```

Comment: He needs an array of Vectors.

Comment: Yes, the unchangeable constraint is array of vectors.

Comment: Juanchopanza, for now, let's ignore the dangers and assumptions.

Comment: Djon, The real program does not have any significant changes.

Comment: @casiocar I added an example using a size 2 array.

Comment: Juan, my compiler doesn't support std::array

Comment: @casiocar look at the last code example. It does not use `std::array`. It uses a plain C size-2 array.

Comment: Thanks, your method signature is what I was looking for!

Comment: @juanchopanza What should I do if I want to pass an array of vectors of size n vectors like vector<int> a[n] to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I tried in following way :

```
void writeToVector(ExtensionType extensions [],int size)
{
  for(int i=0,i<size;i++)
   {
     extensions[i].push_back("A");
   }
}

int main()
{
  const int ARRAY_SIZE=2;
  ExtensionType extensions[ARRAY_SIZE];
  getExtensions(extensions,ARRAY_SIZE);
}
```